# Unable to spawn object.urdf in Gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I just started learning ROS recently and I was going through the tutorial for Gazebo package. When I tried to follow the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/SpawningObjectInSimulation) to spawn an object, even  though I have already created the object.urdf file, the command in 2.3 returns the following: loading model xml from file  Error: file does not exist

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Thanks!
Tom

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36462/unable-to-spawn-object.urdf-in-gazebo/) by [TomWu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2605/tomwu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2012-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, change your directory to where your object.urdf file is then type this command below

rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file object.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model my_object

then i guess it is going to work

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2